# What are some benefits of local currencies?

Tags: currency, currency-exchange

Lets say that we have in my country Greece there is an Island Crete that it has big production (agriculture,small banks etc.) and produces big surplus compared with other parts of Greece and the people there wanted to create there own currency in order to influence their economy and economic policies. What are some benefits for those people in such scenario?

Comment: Google "community currency". There is a whole journal devoted to these questions. The experience in Brazil with the Palma is particularly noteworthy.